# A basis of a module is a minimal spanning set.

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

This is from Roman's *Advanced Linear Algebra*.

> **Theorem 4.4** Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis for an $R$-module $M$. Then 
>   $(1) \ \mathcal{B}$ is a minimal spanning set.  
>   $(2) \ \mathcal{B}$ is a maximal linearly independent set.

Do they mean for all spanning sets $\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{C}$, or are they talking about cardinality?

Comment: They are talking about inclusion. The cardinality claim is false without more assumptions (we need that $R$ have the Invariant Basis Number (IBN) property).

Comment: They do not mean that $B$ is a subset of each spanning set. They mean that you cannot remove an element from $B$ and still have a spanning set. In other words, they don't say that $B$ is a smallest element, they say it is a minimum in the lattice of spanning sets, ordered by inclusion.

Comment: Thanks guys, this makes sense now :D  I love modules :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not mean that $B$ is a subset of each spanning set. They mean that you cannot remove any element from $B$ and still have a spanning set. In other words, they don't say that $B$ is a smallest element, but rather that it is a minimum in the lattice of all spanning sets, ordered by inclusion.